# How to connect bluetooth mouse on Mac using keyboard only

Tags: mac, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I want to connect a bluetooth mouse to my Mac Studio using a keyboard only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking online for an answer but couldn't find one. After some trial and error however I figured out a solution that worked.

1. Press `command` + `space` to open "Spotlight Search"
2. Type "Terminal" and enter.
3. Enable "Full Keyboard Access" with the command `defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 2`.
4. Restart your computer.
5. Press `command` + `space` to open "Spotlight Search"
6. Type "Settings" and to open the system settings.
7. Use arrow keys to navigate to the "Bluetooth" settings and press `tap`.
8. Use `tab` to find the bluetooth device and press `enter` to connect to the device.